# Pivot table collection not updating after sync

Tags: eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.8

I'm re-implementing the code for an online journal in Laravel 5.8/MySQL. I have a users table and a papers table, which have a many-to-many relationship. I am using jQuery/Ajax to modify the list of authors for a given paper, essentially using sync() to load an updated list of authors. The pivot table includes an integer column identifying the position of that author in the list of authors. I have the code working, in so far as it updates the DB correctly, except that the collection of authors does not update after the sync().

I have worked around the problem by creating a new connection to the DB,  but I feel there should be a more efficient way of doing this.

The relevant sections of the models are:

Paper model

```php
    public function authorCollection()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'paperauthors', 'paper_id', 'author_id')->withPivot('notes','authorNum');
    }
```

User model

```php
    public function papers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Paper', 'paperauthors', 'author_id', 'paper_id')->withPivot('notes','authorNum');
    }
```

The code to update the author list is

```php
    $sync = array();
    // set up array for the sync operation, $authors is derived from the Ajax POST request
    foreach($authors as $auth) {
         $sync[$auth->id] = ['authorNum'=>intval($auth->authorNum)];
    }
    $paper->authorCollection()->sync($sync);
    $paper->save();
    // $paper->authorCollection still has the old data unless I add the following line
    $paper = Paper::where('id',$request->id)->first();
```

I would have expected the collection to contain the updated data automatically - is there a function I can use to update it, or do I have to recreate the connection?

Comment: You can reload the relationship: `$paper->load('authorCollection')` Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you Jonas - that's what I was looking for.